# Mudar fonte padrão

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando mudar a fonte de uma página que estou montando com bootstrap, mas por algum motivo ela não aceita. Fiz os seguintes passos:

**No HTML:**

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

**No bootstrap.css:**

```
html {
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
      -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

**No bootstrap.min.css:**

```
{font-family: 'Indie Flower', sans-serif;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%}
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Será que ela está sendo sobrescrita em algum lugar? Teste com !important por via das dúvidas, se funcionar procure onde ela está sendo substituída,

Comment: Adicionando !important no css deve funcionar. Verifica também se a url das fontes está correta.

Comment: Procure a tag body no bootstrap.min.css e coloque a fonte de sua escolha como primeira opção.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O ideal, é você não editar o código fonte do `bootstrap`, assim evita de mexer em coisas que não gostaria. Para trabalhar com um outra fonte padrão, você pode fazer como fez no próprio `html`:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

E editar a fonte padrão na customização que o próprio `bootstrap` oferece [aqui](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#typography).